# How to use equals method in java using instanceof for 2d arrays?

Tags: equals, multidimensional-array, instanceof

/*I am trying to write an equals method using instanceof for 2d arrays (board is a Chess field that holds a 2d array of Piece). I think I got most of it but I'm stuck trying to write the last part. Since it's an equals method, I want the Object obj's board to return true if it's equal to the current object board and false otherwise*/

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this)
            return true;
        else
            if (!(obj instanceof Chess))
                return false;
            else {
                Chess ch= (Chess) obj;
                for (int col=0; col<8; col++)
                    for (int row=0; row<8; row++)
                        //stuck here

            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparisons like these are usually somewhat confusing due to the pathing. I'm not sure what your chessboard or your pieces are, so I will give you the basic logic. If you have null spaces in cells with no pieces, you get to write additional logic within the for loop, but ultimately, once you complete the traversal of the two for loops, you can assume they're equal.

```
        else {
            Chess ch= (Chess) obj;
            for (int col=0; col<8; col++) {
                for (int row=0; row<8; row++) {
                    if this.board[col][row].equals(ch.board[col][row]) {
                        return false; //if any piece doesn't match, it's not equal, we can stop
                    }
                }
            }
            // we iterated through everything, and didn't find anything mismatched
            //might as well say they're equal
            return true;
        }
```